# Hollow triangle with java nested for loops

Tags: java

How would I create a hollow triangle with Java and nested for loops? I've gotten solid triangles to work, but I'm not sure where to start with the hollow ones.

Expected output:

```
**********
 *       *
  *      *
   *     *
    *    *
     *   *
      *  *
       * *
        **
         *
```

EDIT:
This is my code for creating solid triangles:

```
String print = "";
char c = '*';
int size = 5;
for(int i=0;i<=size;i++) {
    for(int j=size;j>i;j--) {
         print+=c;
    }
    print+="\n";
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have for creating solid triangles. It shouldn't be hard to adapt that for creating hollow ones.

Comment: Edited post to include solid triangle code

Comment: So, for a "hollow" triangle, it wouldn't hurt to figure out which rows need to have `*`s removed to make the row "hollow", and which `*`s need to remain for the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample modification of your loop

```
int size = 5;
String print = "";
for(int i=0;i<=size;i++) {
    print += "*";
    for(int j=size;j>i;j--) 
         print+= (i==0)?"*":" ";
    print += "*\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really do your own homework. But since I am feeling particularly generous...

```
int width = 10;
char bound = '*';
char filler = ' ';

// Outer loop on i loops over rows
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    // Inner loop on j loops over columns
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0) // first line is completely full
            Console.Write(bound);

        else if(j == i)
            Console.Write(bound);

        else if(j == (width-1))
            Console.Write(bound);

        else
            Console.Write(filler);
    }

    // Move to next row on the console
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Perhaps not the most efficient thing in the world, but it works.

Comment: Oops my answer was in C# and not Java. Should be trivial to convert it.

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll give it a try and attempt to understand it. It also isn't my homework :P Just something I'm doing in an attempt to understand for loops

Comment: Glad to hear it's not your homework. One tip, you can't really reverse the inner loop because you're outputting on the console, so you have to always move "right and down". Although you could move the cursor around and go backwards, it is easier to code the solution to follow the natural flow of the console.